# Open HttpResponse in a new tab

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, httpresponse

I have the following case.
I am creating a filestream from a pdf file.
after the reponse the generated PDF will be opened in the same tab to print, save etc.

The question is: HOW DO I CHANGE THIS CODE SO IT WILL OPEN IN A NEW TAB (OR WINDOW)?

```
string filepath = String.Format(*Path to file*);            
string filename = *Filename*;

            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                fs.CopyTo(ms);
                var docLength = fs.Length;
                fs.Close();

                WebClient req = new WebClient();
                HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                response.Clear();
                response.ClearContent();
                response.ClearHeaders();
                response.BufferOutput = true;
                Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
                response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + filename);
                response.AddHeader("Content-Length", docLength.ToString());

                //response.Write("<script>");
                //response.Write("window.open('" + filepath + "',_newtab');");
                //response.Write("</script>");

                byte[] data = req.DownloadData(filepath);
                response.BinaryWrite(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Here I log the exception to a text file. 
            }
            finally
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
                HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.
            }
```

I have tried several options, but still not found a solution that works for me.
Can someone help me with this.
This function is not directly triggered by a button.

the button triggers another method which generates some other stuff and after that it triggers the method described above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("window.open('../LOCATION/pages/FILENAME.pdf', '_newtab');");
Response.Write("</script>");
```

Comment: This piece of code i already had in my code (in comments because it didn't work)
Is this the right location or do i need to place this at the end

Comment: Just try placing below

Comment: Thanks but already tried that also I tried to use _blank instead of _newtab.
Still opening in the same tab.

Comment: load another page and onload provide the code to display pdf

Comment: Do you have an example or link.
Another solution can be a code behind method which triggers a jQuery method. with parameters.

But I do not know how to do that.
(Triggering a jquery method is easy but trigger a method with parameters is new for me).